# Redirecting to flask route function from clicking a table row

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, onclick

I have a table with a number of rows and I am looking for how to set up the html/js to allow for a user to click anywhere on the table row element and have it redirect them to a flask route such as `/group/<group_id>`

Row shown here:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to use the id in a data-id attribute on the row to fill in the dynamic portion of the flask route. I don't want to use a button which could use an `<a>` so I'm looking for an alternative.

Flask routes.py

```py
@bp.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def job_item(job_id):

    print('Redirect successful')
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

Row Element

```
<tr class="text-center" id="job-{{ job.id }}" data-job-id="job-{{ job.id }}">
```

Comment: put `<tr>` inside `<a>` or in every `<td>` use `<a>`. OR you have to write JavaScript code for this. Do you have any JavaScript code for this? If you have JavaScript then you should show it in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Javascript with onclick event that will pass in the id of the element.

Assuming that you are using Jinja templating,

Row element should be

```
<tr class="text-center with-click" onclick="goToJob('job-{{ job.id }}')" id="job-{{ job.id }}" data-job-id="job-{{ job.id }}">
```

The script function should be

```
function goToJob(strId) {
    job_id = parseInt(strId.split("-")[1]);
    alert(job_id);
}
```

You can replace the alert action with anything, and in your case with a GET/POST request to `/jobs/<job_id>`

Some styling can be added to help improve the UX

```
<style>
  tr.with-click:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```